# Stop opening files automatically when I load my solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, crash, freeze

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, and have created a bug **so monumental**, whenever I load my project, visual studio just hangs...it doesn't crash and even the system still thinks the application is responding!?

Basically I put a sort of `Update();` in the `WndProc` for a `Control`, and now it Just Updates itself and all it's siblings - **forever**, and never let's me get a click in edgeways!

*Silly of me I know!*

I've deleted all binaries in an attempt to stop this lunacy, but every time I reload the project - there it is; a form with a few buttons that just update endlessly!

How can I stop this?

I need to recompile the solution, but I can't even do that with it automatically loading up the designer...

Can I edit a csproj or something to stop the solution automatically loading up these files?

Comment: Guessing not under source control to roll back?

Comment: Why can't you just edit the code file on disk to add a `return;` at the top of the offending method?

Comment: Does not solve your problem, but if you ever had this problem with a visual studio plugin instead of a solution you are opening you can start visual studio in [SafeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just open the offending file using another text editor (Notepad) and simply remove (or comment out) the line(s) of code that create(s) the bug. Then re-open the solution in Visual Studio.

After you edit the file in question outside of Visual Studio, you can clean-up the Obj cache and binaries but most likely the problem will go away even without having to delete the intermediate files and the binaries.

As another user pointed out, you could also remove the solution user options (.suo) file and start Visual Studio and then open the offending file by right-clicking on it and making sure to choose "View Code" so as not to trigger the designer and edit the code to remove the problem. Either way should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you delete the .suo file for that solution and then open it should give you an empty 'left' side.